# Location dependent rendering of locations?

Tags: plugins

I have a client who has multiple offices. Instead of listing all the locations out in the footer, they'd like to show the only one office which is closest to the user.

What would be the best solution for this? Is there a plugin which would easily handle this?

Comment: plugin recommendations are off topic here

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what accuracy you need to find out?
World? State? City?

You can use Wordpress plugin some kind of IP Locator or Geolocation IP detection... Or you can use your own code to determinate IP address of visior. But it is could be difficult, because some providers have dynamic external IP and your found address is not precise even within multiple states.. I am from Poland and my provider is Orange, French company, and you can see my external IP as from French...

So you can use some AJAX methods to retrieve precise location as possible from client-side.

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

Or pure javascript without jQuery using  https://geolocation-db.com service to call back IP location from client to server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geo City Locator by geolocation-db.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
    <div>Postal: <span id="postal"></span></div>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
    <div>IP address: <span id="ipv4"></span></div>                             
</body>
<script>

    var country = document.getElementById('country');
    var state = document.getElementById('state');
    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    var postal = document.getElementById('postal');
    var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
    var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipv4');

    function callback(data)
    {
        country.innerHTML = data.country_name;
        state.innerHTML = data.state;
        city.innerHTML = data.city;
        postal.innerHTML = data.postal;
        latitude.innerHTML = data.latitude;
        longitude.innerHTML = data.longitude;
        ip.innerHTML = data.IPv4;
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://geoilocation-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    h.parentNode.insertBefore(script, h);

</script> 
</html>
```

Or can try to use PHP server-side library GeoIP2:

```
 <?php
require_once("geoip2.phar");
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
// City DB
$reader = new Reader('/path/to/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
$record = $reader->city($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
// or for Country DB
// $reader = new Reader('/path/to/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
// $record = $reader->country($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
print($record->country->isoCode . "\n");
print($record->country->name . "\n");
print($record->country->names['zh-CN'] . "\n");
print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->name . "\n");
print($record->mostSpecificSubdivision->isoCode . "\n");
print($record->city->name . "\n");
print($record->postal->code . "\n");
print($record->location->latitude . "\n");
print($record->location->longitude . "\n");
$>
```

Try yourself which method suits your requirements... as I said it's all about exactly how you want to locate the visitor

Comment: Also: If we're talking about EU (or customers in the EU), I would argue that it would need explicit opt in to use 3rd party service to locate in order to show nearest location.

Comment: This code as is would be illegal tracking in numerous countries and states, you need to ask consent before contacting `https://geolocation-db.com/`

Comment: Yes, that's true... But, he asked for a solution not for legal matters. That's his problem when he uses such a thing...

Comment: coincidentally this is for a law firm in the US so I am sure they got this covered. I haven't found a decent plugin for this yet but am inclined to use one since I don't think hand-coding this would be worth the effort. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Hewe For many plugin in WP is about Code yourself or Pay... If you are developer and programmer of website or they pay you to do this you must solve this in accordance with the law. Lawyers tell you about law, but you as programmer is responsible to code this according law